# Dominated convergence theorem for integrals with singularity

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded region in $R^3$ and for each $x\in\Omega $ define

$$I(x) = \int_\Omega \dfrac{1}{|x-y|}dy$$

I want to show that $I$ is differentiable by differentiating $I$ under the integral, but I am having a difficulty with finding a dominating function for the integrand. By using mean value theorem, I was able to get

$$(I(x+he_i)-I(x))/h = \int_\Omega \dfrac{x+k-y}{|x+ke_i-y|^3} dy$$
where $k$ is a real number with $|k|<h$, but how do I get a dominating function for this integrand independent of $k$?

A few other references that I looked up seems to simply say that:

$|\partial_{x_i} \dfrac{1}{|x-y|} | \leq \dfrac{1}{|x-y|^2}$ and since the function on the right hand side is integrable, we can differentiate under the integral, but I do not understand this argument. Could you please explain?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Sorry for the confusion. I meant to say $R^3$, as the integrand arises as a newtonian potential

Comment: In such a case it is enough to check that by integrating along shells $$\iiint_{\|x\|\leq \rho}\frac{d\mu}{\|x\|} = 4\pi\int_{0}^{\rho}\frac{r^2}{r}\,dr = 2\pi\rho^2 $$

Comment: If you decompose $\Omega$ as a union of disjoint open balls and use the previous result, differentiability is a straightforward consequence.